# Elixir only works in the C:\Windows\System32 directory

Tags: elixir

Elixir only works in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory.

For example:

[image: Elixir only works in the C:\Windows\System32 directory]

Also, if I write just elixir in the console - it will work

[image: elixir]

My path is valid

[image: path]

how i can fix it?

Comment: Is there an `elixir.bat` in `System32` that's different to the one in `Program Files`?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, i haven't elixir.bat in System32.

Comment: How did you install elixir?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, thank you, i add C:\WINDOWS\System32 in path and this start work.